# Android textView to containt a lot of text

Tags: android, text, textview

Hy! I am learning Android programming and I want to know is it possible to type a lot of text in TextView. So far, i tried to put some infos, for example email adresses, phone numbers etc with blank rows so it looks nice, but my TextView cant hold all that text . What should I do ? 
I tried to put my text as string in res/values/strings.xml file, but nothing change...

EDIT: I have fixed my problem. I saved my large string into string.xml file putting \n to format it so it looks nice.

Comment: ur textview can't hold all that text ? means what ?

Answer (score 3):

Within the xml you can wrap your `TextView` in a `ScrollView` to make the `TextView` scrollable.

```
<SrollView>
     <TextView
          attributes for TextView here
     />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

properties of your `TextView` in your layout's xml file.

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Then put:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

in your code.

it scrolls automatically without any issues, No need to use ScrollView.